# Suitable javascript parser to be used with urlopen

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://search.wcad.org/Property-Detail?PropertyQuickRefID=R000017&PartyQuickRefID=O0532572'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())
print soup
```

The print statement displays very complicated text structure and it is difficult to extract variables. What is the better way to extract variables like `Legal Description`

Answer (score 2):

*You don't need to parse JavaScript* to get the "Legal Description" value - you need to parse HTML and `BeautifulSoup` HTML parser can do the job. Locate the `td` element "by 'Legal Description' text" and then get the next `td` element:

```
soup.find("td", text="Legal Description").find_next_sibling("td").get_text()
```

---

Note: you are using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 - it is very outdated and not maintained - switch to the 4th version:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And change your import from:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you can do this with `urllib2` I would recommend to use `requests`. 
The `id` is unique for each field, so you can get the text directly by finding the element using `id`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://search.wcad.org/Property-Detail?PropertyQuickRefID=R000017&PartyQuickRefID=O0532572"

html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
text = soup.find("td", id="dnn_ctr1460_View_tdGILegalDescription").get_text()
print(text)
```

NOTE: I've used `Beautifulsoup` version 4. To install it use this command - `pip install bs4`.